# Process builder are scheduled actions independent?

Tags: process-builder, scheduled-action

I have scheduled actions that run at certain times dependant on a custom field.

Based on my scheduled actions, It will wait 30 days and do something. After the 30 days, it will run the next schedule   action which should run 2 days after.So this will automatically run as already 30 days.

I am assuming the scheduled action in front must finish before the second one starts?

Question) Are scheduled actions independent?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependency of scheduled action is based on the criteria on which you are scheduling the action.

According to the configuration of your use case, all are independent.

For more information, refer [How Does Salesforce Process Scheduled Actions?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_limits_scheduled_processing.htm&type=5)